# Re-sampling data does not work at all required time-rates

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have time series data at a 1-minute sampling rate generated as

```
library(xts)
#create timestamp with 1 mintue sampling rage
timerange <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-06-09"),as.POSIXct("2016-06-22 23:59:59"), by = "1 min")
# create xts object
data_xts <- xts(rnorm(length(timerange),200,5),timerange)
```

Now, I want to resample (change sampling rate) it to 50 minutes rate.So, I have created a custom function as:

```
resample_data_minutely_daywise <- function(data_xts,xminutes) {
  day_data <- split.xts(data_xts,"days",k=1) # divide data daywise
  # Now resample data according to parameter xminutes
  day_list <- lapply(day_data, function(x) { 
    ds_data <- period.apply(x,INDEX = endpoints(index(x), on = "minutes", k = xminutes ), FUN= mean)
    align_data <- align.time(ds_data,xminutes*60) # aligning to x seconds
    return(align_data)
  })
  return(day_list)
}
```

This function takes timeseries data and required sampling frequency as input. Next, it splits data daywise and finally for each day it changes sampling by taking mean.

Now, whenever I call this function as

```
p <- resample_data_minutely_daywise(data_xts,50)
sapply(p,length) # check no. of observations in each day
```

The output is:

```
 sapply(p,length) # check no. of observations in each day
 [1] 30 30 30 29 29 30 30 30 29 29 30 30 30 29
```

This shows that not every day contains the same number of readings. Few days contains 29 and some contain 30 observations. What can be the reason for this unknown behavior. Note whenever I resample at 10, 20,30,60 minutes every day contains the same number of readings. This problem only happens when I try for 50 minutes.

Comment: 50 does not divide evenly into each day, so some obs. start on the next day and you get 1 less.

Comment: @StevenMortimer But I take each day separately and then try to combine at 50 mins rate.

Comment: Look at `p`. Each of your days does not start at 00:00:00. And the first observation of the next day is sometimes included.

Comment: @ChiPak, Yes, I think that `period.apply` is buggy. Apart from 50 min, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is that `period.apply()` uses `endpoints()` to find where the breaks are, and `endpoints()` output is always offset from the UNIX epoch/origin (1970-01-01 00:00:00). But you want the breaks to be offset from midnight of the current day.

You can still do that with `period.apply()`, but you need to calculate custom break points. In your case, you can do that by looking for seconds since the beginning of the day that are multiples of `xminutes`.

```
resample_data_minutely_daywise <- function(data_xts,xminutes) {
  day_data <- split.xts(data_xts,"days",k=1) # divide data daywise
  # Now resample data according to parameter xminutes
  day_list <- lapply(day_data, function(x) { 
    timeT <- .index(x) - .index(x)[1]
    # when does timeT cross a multiple of xminutes?
    ep <- which(timeT %% (xminutes * 60) <= 0)
    # endpoints must start with zero and end with nrow
    ep <- c(0, ep, nrow(x))
    # ...and be unique
    ep <- unique(ep)
    ds_data <- period.apply(x, INDEX = ep, FUN = mean)
    align_data <- align.time(ds_data,xminutes*60) # aligning to x seconds
    return(align_data)
  })
  return(day_list)
}
p <- resample_data_minutely_daywise(data_xts,50)
sapply(p,length)
# [1] 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
```

Comment: After applying `period.apply`, I loose timestamps. I tried to convert `ep` indices into time indices then `period.apply` throws error as `Error in `[.xts`(x, (INDEX[y] + 1):INDEX[y + 1]) : subscript out of bounds`. I need timestamps of  `align_data`

Comment: @HaroonRashid: see my edit. If that doesn't solve your problem, please provide an example that reproduces what you describe.  Because I don't have an issue with the example in your question.